# Rxjava2 how to return cached values if time does't come out

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a question. I have simple Observable.

```
public interface CitiesApi {
    @GET("location/cities")
    Observable<List<City>> getCities(@Query("country") String countryId);
}
```

Also I have class(manager), which save data from this observable and turn it over to activity or presenter.

```
public class Manager {

    @Inject
    CitiesApi mCitiesApi;

    private Date mDate;
    private List<City> mCities;

    public Observable<List<City>> getObservable() {
        return mCitiesApi.getCities("123");
    }      
}
```

Question: When i subscribe on this observable, and

> current time - last subscribe time < 10 min(or other range, it doesn't
>   matter...)

I want to call onNext with old data. But if time difference > 10 i want to download data from web (return original observable). I don't want to use retrofit cache, cause i could change this list manually.

Comment: you can do it before even you call your Observable. You test on your cached data, it it's less that 10min, your just return data otherwise you make your network call and you update your cached data and the time

Comment: Could you show me, how observable will be look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Observable must llok like that:

```
public Observable<List<City>> getObservable() {

if (cacheTime > 10){ //If cached data time is greater than 10min, you make your network call.
        return mCitiesApi.getCities("123");
} else{
    return Observable.just(getChachedData("123")) //Where getChachedData is a method that return a list of your cached data. 
}
}
```